# std::copy from vector's position to vector's position

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

This probably me being extremely tired, but I can't figure out how to copy part of a vector into a new vector.

What I am trying to do, is find inside an std::vector (where char is typedefed as byte) where the starting tag is, and copy the data from there, up to the closing tag (which is at the end, and is 7 chars long).

```
typedef char byte;
std::vector<byte> imagebytes;
std::vector<byte> bytearray_;

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < bytearray_.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( (i + 5) < (bytearray_.size()-7) )
    {
        std::string temp ( &bytearray_[i], 5 );

        if ( temp == "<IMG>" )
        {
            // This is what isn't working
            std::copy( std::vector<byte>::iterator( bytearray_.begin() + i + 5 ),
                       std::vector<byte>::iterator( bytearray_.end() - 7 )
                       std::back_inserter( imagebytes) );
        }
    }   
}
```

I know this loop looks horrible, I am open to suggestions!
Please note, bytearray_ contains raw bytes of images, or audio files. Hence the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple: just copy, don't loop. The loop is already inside `std::copy`.

```
typedef char byte;
std::vector<byte> imagebytes;
std::vector<byte> bytearray_;

// Contents of bytearray_ is assigned here.
// Assume bytearray_ is long enough.

std::copy(bytearray_.begin() + 5,
          bytearray_.end() - 7,
           std::back_inserter( imagebytes) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of copying you can also construct a new vector directly from the existing one:

```
std::vector<byte> imagebytes(bytearray_.begin() + i + 5, bytearray_.end() - 7);
```